# Definitions of closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Good day,

In *Topology* (2015) by Marco Manetti, the definition of a closed set is given as:

> A subset $C\subset X$ in $\Bbb R^n$ is called **closed** in $X$ if it coincides with the set of points of $X$ that adhere to $C$. Equivalently, $C$ is closed in $X$ if, for any $x\in X-C= \{x\in X|x\notin C\} $, a number $\delta \gt 0$ exists such that $d(x,y) \ge \delta$ for every $y \in C$.

I had a look at "Closed Set" from Wolfram MathWorld, which states that:

> The point-set topological definition of a closed set is a set which contains all of its limit points.

Do these definitions therefore imply that the set of points that adhere to $C$ is in fact the set of limit points of $C$?

If I have an interval $C \subset \Bbb R$ e.g. $-1 \lt y \lt 1$ and a point $x=2$, does this mean I can say that the interval is closed because there is a $\delta = 0.5 \gt 0 $ such that $d(x,y)=x-y \ge \delta$ for every $y \in C$ ? Would this same reasoning also apply if $C$ was instead $-1 \le y \le 1$ ?

Best wishes

Comment: No. The first definition said "for every $x$". You picked just one special $x$.

Comment: "Any $x$" is the same as "every $x$"?

Comment: Yes. Notice though that every $x$ will have its own $\delta$. What the first definition is saying is that no matter what $x$ you pick, you should find a corresponding $\delta$

Comment: I see. But if I always pick an $x \in X-C$, how will it be possible to have a $\delta = 0$, since $x$ is not even in $C$ ? Shouldn't this therefore mean that all sets are closed?

Comment: $\delta$ cannot be zero! It must be strictly positive.

Comment: That's the part I'm confused about. Since I'm picking an $x$ from $X-C$, shouldn't $\delta$ always be strictly positive then? If so, then according to the first definition, no matter what $C$ I have it will always be closed.

Comment: take your example $C=(-1,1)$. Then $x=2 \in X-C$, but you will not be able to find a positive $\delta$ for it. So $C$ is not closed.

Comment: If the distance $d(x,y)=x-y$ then $2-(-1,1) = (1,3)$ hence $\delta \gt 1$, no?

Comment: sorry I meant $x=1$. Then Delta is zero which is bad.

Comment: @GaussTheBauss I see - thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite, but almost. A point $x$ adheres to $C$ (in a metric space) iff for every $\delta > 0$, the ball $B(x,\delta)$ intersects $C$. In particular, this holds for all $x$ that are in $C$ trivially (as $x$ is always in $B(x,\delta)$, regardless of $\delta>0$). The set of adherence points of $C$ is then called the closure of $C$, also denoted $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ or $\overline{A}$, and a set is closed iff $C = \overline{C}$ (which is saying that $C$ contains all its adherence points, because already $C \subseteq \overline{C}$, as remarked).

A limit point $x$ of $C$ is a point $x$ such that for every $\delta > 0$, $B(x,\delta)$ intersects $C \setminus \{x\}$, or every ball around $x$ contains a point of $C$ **other than** $x$. In this case a point $x$ in $C$ need not be a limit point of $C$: all points that are not have *some* ball $B(x,\delta)$ around it such that $B(x,\delta) \cap C = \{x\}$; i.e. the ball intersects $C$ only in $x$. Such $x$ are called isolated points of $C$. E.g. for $C = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$, $2$ is such a point, or in $C = \mathbb{Z}$, all points are such (take $\delta = 1$ in both cases). Another equivalent definition of being closed is that the set of limit points of $C$, denoted $C'$, is a subset of $C$, or $C$ contains all its limit points. One easily shows that $\overline{C} = C \cup C'$.

The equivalence of the two definitions in your first statement is quite clear. $C$ is closed if it coincides with the set of points that adhere to it. I.e. $C = \overline{C}$. This is clearly the same as that when $x \notin C$, then $x \notin \overline{C}$, i.e. every point not in $C$ cannot adhere to it, which means that there exists *some* $\delta > 0$ such that $B(x, \delta) \cap C = \emptyset$ (this is the logical negation of being an adherence point!), and this means exactly that for all $y \in C$, $d(x,y) \ge \delta$ (otherwise $y \in C$ would have been in the open ball!).

Also by definition all limit points are adherence points (it's a stronger condition), but not reversely as we can have isolated points in $C$, which are adherence points but not limit points. But $C$ is closed iff it contains all its adherence points, iff it contains all its limit points.

Comment: This has been most illuminating; thank you :)